# Adding items to the Windows control box

Tags: c#, winforms, icons, controlbox

Is there anyway to add an item to the control box (wheres the close, minimize and maximize buttons are) with my custom icon in C#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like drawing the button yourself with the Win32 API is the only way.

http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/41/207281.aspx

http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.drawing/browse_thread/thread/7b8e66d3803d8c7?hl=en&lr&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&rnum=3&pli=1

http://www.developmentnow.com/g/36_2003_11_0_0_202324/Adding-buttons-to-the-forms-title-bar.htm